# Chrome packaged app install requires sign-in?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am not sure if this is new behavior, but I have noticed that it is possible to install chrome *extensions* from the web store without signing in to Chrome, but currently installing any *packaged app* (even those which do not request "identity" permissions) is gated by signing into chrome with a Google account.

Is this a bug, or an attempt by Google to get more people to create Google accounts?

Comment: Started a thread on Chromium-apps group: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/62riAWw2ogk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time (Sept 2013) Packaged Apps offer developers an always signed in user, and offers users a consistent experience across all devices where they sign into Chrome. All APIs that rely on a signed in user are available and will work as expected. Identity is one, but so are the various storage APIs that rely on chrome sync. The application launcher experience is also tied to an individual, synchronizing installed apps to all devices they use.

The team has had some discussions about possible future support of apps not tied to an individual, in incognito or guest mode, etc. If you have thoughts or use cases to share the most productive place to do so is on [chromium-apps](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-apps).

Comment: This is what I was afraid of! Of course, I could have realized that chrome.storage.sync implies the user is logged-in. What happens when the user is logged out, then (i.e. password change, etc)? The apps are "greyed" out?

Comment: Don't be afraid, voice your use cases on chromium-apps list. I speculate that apps/extensions would no longer sync, and data stored locally would no longer sync, similar to how other Chrome features continue to work but not sync when the user isn't signed in. Chrome prompts to encourage users to fix a broken sync state.

Answer (score 2):

You can allow users install extensions and apps without having logged into Google Account when using [Inline installation](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation) on your website.

[image]

If you are regular user and just want to install extension from Chrome Web Store without signing in you can use [Chrome Extensions Downloader](http://chrome-extension-downloader.com/) website